# Refresh html that is loaded into iframe with jQuery tab

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe, tabs

Very new to this...

My site http://www.daveknispel.com.au is where I have the issue.

I use jQuery to load html pages into iFrames with a tab system. Their is 2 levels of this, so a similar tab system is used in a html within the iFrame. The problem is when I toggle on the original page the html in the iFrame with the toggle doesn't refresh to its initial state.

Index.html > has |work| |contact| |resume| tabs

within work.html which sits within an iframe on index.html it has a series of images that act as tabs 
so if you press a tab say ghostbuster, my ghostbusters portfolio html appears within the frame.

If now you press |work| again I want the iframe to reset to the original work.html

Not sure if this is clear but hopefully.

```
// JavaScript Document

$("document").ready(function(){
        $('#content > div').hide();
        $('#content div:first').show();
        $('.nav-wrapper ul li:first').addClass('active');
        $('.nav-wrapper ul li a').click(function(){
        $('.nav-wrapper ul li').removeClass('active');
        $(this).parent().addClass('active');
        var currentTab = $(this).attr('href');
        $('#content > div').hide();
        $(currentTab).fadeIn(400).fadeIn('slow');
        return false;
        });
});
```

//index.html

```
 <div class="nav-wrapper">
<div class="menu">
   <ul>
     <li><a class="fill-div" href="#work"  onclick="work.html.refresh"><h2>work</h2></a></li>
     <li><a class="fill-div" href="#about"><h2>about/contact</h2></a></li>
     <li><a class="fill-div" href="#resume"><h2>resume</h2></a></li>
   </ul>
</div> 

   <div id="content">

   <div id="work">
   <iframe src="work.html" width="860px" height="1380px" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" seamless></iframe>
   </div>
   <div id="about">
   <iframe src="about.html" width="860px" height="1500px" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" seamless></iframe>
   </div>
   <div id="resume">
   <iframe src="resume.html" width="860px" height="1216px" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" seamless></iframe>
   </div>


   </div>
</div>
```

//work.html

```
    <div class="nav-wrapper">

<div id="content">
<div class="menu2">

<ul>

<div class="frameProject">
<li><a class="fill-div" href="#metro">
<img src="img/metro.jpg" alt="Metropolitan Hotel">
<h3> Metropolitan Hotel </h3></a></li>
<h4> Web, Print & Digital </h4>
</div>

<div class="frameProject">
<li><a class="fill-div" href="#ghostbusters">
<img src="img/ghostbusters.jpg" alt="Ghostbusters">
<h3> Ghostbusters </h3></a></li>
<h4> Title Sequence </h4>
</div>

<div class="frameProject">
<li><a class="fill-div" href="#uep">
<img src="img/uep.jpg" alt="UEP Pty. Ltd.">
<h3> UEP </h3></a></li>
<h4> Website & Build </h4>
</div>

<div class="frameProject">
<li><a class="fill-div" href="#science">
<img src="img/science.jpg" alt="Science Q and A">
<h3> Science Q and A </h3></a></li>
<h4> Logo Design </h4>
</div>

<div class="frameProject">
<li><a class="fill-div" href="#gonski">
<img src="img/gonski.jpg" alt="Gonski Review">
<h3> Gonski Review </h3></a></li>
<h4> Infographic Animation </h4>
</div>

<div class="frameProject">
<li><a class="fill-div" href="#mylife">
<img src="img/mylife.jpg" alt="My Life Network">
<h3> My Life Network </h3></a></li>
<h4> Logo & Web Design </h4>
</div>

<div class="frameProject">
<li><a class="fill-div" href="#gameandwatch">
<img src="img/gameandwatch.jpg" alt="Game and Watch"> 
<h3> Game and Watch </h3></a></li>
<h4> Design & Programming </h4> 
</div>

<div class="frameProject">
<li><a class="fill-div" href="#barnbrook">
<img src="img/barnbrook.jpg" alt="Barnbrook">
<h3> Jonathon Barnbrook </h3></a></li>
<h4> Poster Design </h4>
</div>

<div class="frameProject">
<li><a class="fill-div" href="#cerberus">
<img src="img/cerberus.jpg" alt="Cerberus">
<h3> Cerberus v Hercules </h3></a></li>
<h4> Design </h4>
</div>

<div class="frameProject">
<li><a class="fill-div" href="#whenjooturns">
<img src="img/joo.jpg" alt="When Joo Turns">
<h3> When Joo Turns </h3></a></li>
<h4> Animation </h4>
</div>

<div class="frameProject">
<li><a class="fill-div" href="#allstar">
<img src="img/afl.jpg" alt="All Star Karaoke">
<h3> All Star Karaoke </h3></a></li>
<h4> Animation </h4>
</div>

<div class="frameProject">
<li><a class="fill-div" href="#iamlife">
<img src="img/iamlife.jpg" alt="I am Life - Film">
<h3> I am Life Film </h3></a></li>
<h4> Assistant Director </h4>
</div>

<div class="frameProject">
<li><a class="fill-div" href="#owlfarm">
<img src="img/owl.jpg" alt="Owl Farm">
<h3> Owl Farm </h3></a></li>
<h4> Logo Design </h4>
</div>

</ul>
</div>


   <div id="metro">
   <iframe src="metro.html" width="840px" height="1216px" frameborder="0" scrolling="yes" seamless></iframe>
   </div>

   <div id="ghostbusters">
   <iframe src="ghostbusters.html" width="840px" height="1216px" frameborder="0" scrolling="yes" seamless></iframe>
   </div>

   <div id="uep">
   <iframe src="uep.html" width="840px" height="1216px" frameborder="0" scrolling="yes" seamless></iframe>
   </div>

   <div id="science">
   <iframe src="science.html" width="840px" height="1216px" frameborder="0" scrolling="yes" seamless></iframe>
   </div>

   <div id="gonski">
   <iframe src="gonski.html" width="840px" height="1216px" frameborder="0" scrolling="yes" seamless></iframe>
   </div>


   <div id="mylife">
   <iframe src="mylife.html" width="840px" height="1216px" frameborder="0" scrolling="yes" seamless></iframe>
   </div>

   <div id="gameandwatch">
   <iframe src="gameandwatch.html" width="840px" height="1216px" frameborder="0" scrolling="yes" seamless></iframe>
   </div>

   <div id="barnbrook">
   <iframe src="barnbrook.html" width="840px" height="1216px" frameborder="0" scrolling="yes" seamless></iframe>
   </div>

   <div id="cerberus">
   <iframe src="cerberus.html" width="840px" height="1216px" frameborder="0" scrolling="yes" seamless></iframe>
   </div>

   <div id="whenjooturns">
   <iframe src="whenjooturns.html" width="840px" height="1216px" frameborder="0" scrolling="yes" seamless></iframe>
   </div>

   <div id="allstar">
   <iframe src="allstar.html" width="840px" height="1216px" frameborder="0" scrolling="yes" seamless></iframe>
   </div>


   <div id="iamlife">
   <iframe src="iamlife.html" width="840px" height="1150px" frameborder="0" scrolling="yes" seamless></iframe>
   </div>

   <div id="owlfarm">
   <iframe src="owlfarm.html" width="840px" height="1216px" frameborder="0" scrolling="yes" seamless></iframe>
   </div>




  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: **Note:** Do not wrap document with quotes; should be `$(document)`

Answer (score 0):

Your solution is a bit convoluted, but here's a way of solving your problem.

```
// JavaScript Document
$("document").ready(function(){
    $('#content > div').hide();
    $('#content div:first').show();
    $('.nav-wrapper ul li:first').addClass('active');
    $('.nav-wrapper ul li a').click(function(){
    $('.nav-wrapper ul li').removeClass('active');
    $(this).parent().addClass('active');
    var currentTab = $(this).attr('href');
    $('#content > div').hide();

    // Added lines. Reset the iframe src to reload the original contents of the iframe.
    var iframe = $(currentTab).find('iframe').get(0);
    iframe.src = iframe.src;

    $(currentTab).fadeIn(400).fadeIn('slow');        
    return false;
    });
});
```

Comment: this solution did work although when you press on the work tab it flashes for a moment on the preselected tab before refreshing... have updated the site...thanks for the help

Comment: Yes, it has to reload the contents of the frame again. You could probably have it wait for the load event before showing the frame first.

Answer (score 0):

This might work:

```
$( "#tabs" ).tabs( "refresh" );
```